# Dependent combo box populating in Dojo Dijit?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dojo combobox  which when the options are changed i need to populate a related second  combo box 
which is co dependent on the value of the first combo box. How can i achieve this. The code i have tried so far is below

html code:

```
<div class="gis_SearchDijit">
<div class="formContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="searchFormDijit">
        <table cellspacing="5" style="width:100%; height: 49px;">
            <tr>
                <td>                       
                    <label for="Customer">Customer:</label>                                        
                      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="Customer"></div> <br />  
                    <label for="Attributes">Search Attribute:</label>      
                     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="Attributes"></div>                     

                    <br />
                    Enter Attribute Value:<input id="searchText" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="name:'searchText',trim:true,required:true,style:'width:100%;'"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="buttonActionBar">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props="busyLabel:'searching',iconClass:'searchIcon'" data-dojo-attach-event="click:search">
                Search
        </div>
</div>
```

```
postCreate: function () { 
                    this.inherited(arguments); 


                    this.populateCmbCustomer(Memory); 

                    var comboBoxDigit = registry.byId("Customer"); 


                    comboBoxDigit.on('change', function (evt) { 
                        alert('on change'); //This alert is triggerd 
                        this.populateCmbCustomerAttribute(Memory); 

                    }); 

   populateCmbCustomer: function (Memory) { 
                var stateStore = new Memory({ 
                    data: [ 
                { name: "Cust  Data", id: "CUST" }, 
                { name: "Owner Data", id: "Owner" }, 
                { name: "Applicant", id: "Applicant" }                     
                    ] 
                }); 

                var comboBoxDigit = registry.byId("Customer");     
                //console.log("COMBO: ", comboBoxDigit); 
                comboBoxDigit.set("store", stateStore); 
            }, 



                 populateCmbCustomerAttribute: function (Memory) { 
                var custAttribute = new Memory({ 
                    data: [ 
                { name: "Custid", id: "Cust" }, 
                { name: "Applicant Id", id: "Applicant" }, 
                { name: "Owner_Id", id: "Owner" } 

                    ] 
                }); 

                var CmbCustomerAttribute = registry.byId("Attributes"); 
                CmbCustomerAttribute.set("store", custAttribute); 
            },
```

Note: the above is just part of the code of my widjet.js.
 I am able to load the first combobox with the options. So now when i chose 'Cust Data'  in my first combobox then custid should be the only option in second combo box. In the same way Owner Data in first then Owner_id in second...But so far i am not able to populate the second combo-box..  Can some one please guide me 
Than You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the query property of the second combo it should look something like this

```
comboBoxDigit.on('change', function (evt) { 
   var CmbCustomerAttribute = registry.byId("Attributes");
   CmbCustomerAttribute.set("query", {filteringProperty: this.get('value')}); //if you dont understand this check out the stores tutorials
});
```

EDIT: [tutorials](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/filteringitems.html#querying) referenced in above code snippet helps clear up the ambiguity of "filteringProperty" quite a bit.

I would also recomend to populate your sencond combo from the beggining with something like this

```
var CmbCustomerAttribute = registry.byId("Attributes");
CmbCustomerAttribute.set("store", store); 
CmbCustomerAttribute.set("query", {id:'nonExistantId'}); //so nothing shows in the combo
```

I think somthing like this is what you are seraching for, any doubts just ask. as cant say mucho more whitout a fiddle or actual code

Comment: Sorry Ricardo ..My bad i have forggoten to add the Html code earlier. I have edit my earlier question.Thank You for the response though. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: so are you trying to create a reusable widget?because if not looks like its overcomplicated

Comment: also what version of dojo are you using

Comment: Yes ricardo i am planning to use it as reusable widget.I have started training on this dojo just 2 days ago hence my knowledge is limited.

Comment: The reason i am having diffrent functions to populate the two comboboxes is to reuse them later.The main objective of posting the question is to poulate the attributes combobox during the onchange event of customer combobox. Thank you Ricardo

Comment: Your solutions guided me..Thank you very much.

Comment: soory, didnt have access to a computer during the weekend or yesterday, but try using the attribute "data-dojo-attach-point" if you are using templated widgets, or save on the "this" variable of your widget object intead of using IDS, as this "polutes" the widget ids(you wont be able to use it and an strage dojo exception wiil occur)